in realm , can't get schema for configuration

i am using realm: ^3.1.0 for the very first time but i can't get schema form my model class.
This is my model class which is private according to the package
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:realm/realm.dart';

@RealmModel()
class _$ProjectModal{
  @RealmPropertyType.int
  late int project_id;

  @RealmPropertyType.string
  late String project_name;

  @RealmPropertyType.int
  late int student_id;

  @RealmPropertyType.string
  late String? image_url;

}

class ProjectTmp extends _$ProjectModal {

  int project_id;

  String project_name;

  int student_id;

  String? image_url;
  ProjectTmp({required this.project_id, required this.project_name, required this.student_id, required this.image_url});

  factory ProjectTmp.fromMap({required Map data}) {
    log(data['image_url'].runtimeType.toString());
    return ProjectTmp(
      project_id: data['project_id'],
      project_name: data['project_name'],
      student_id: data['student_id'],
      image_url: data['image_url'],
    );
  }

}

And Here i want to access schema
import 'package:realm/realm.dart';

import '../data/modal/project_modal.dart';

class RealmHelper{

  RealmHelper._();

  static final RealmHelper instance = RealmHelper._();

  var config = Configuration.local([ProjectModal.schema]);// Shows error at .schema

}


But it shows error at schema .
Error is :The getter 'schema' isn't defined for the type '_$ProjectModal'. (Documentation)
I have tried using it's Child class still i stucks at there.
Have you ever used this package.
i am expecting to use schema directly without getting error.

For some reason can't get part 'student_record_modal.realm.dart'; file

I have solved it by adding part 'project_modal.realm.dart'; on the top of the file if there will show error Ignore it.
just try to dart run realm generate run in the terminal and then i got a new file named .realme.dart and then try to access schemas which can be used.

Yeah this works for me.
